# Data Validation - Drop Down List dependent on adjacent list range values

Tags: excel, vba

Here is an example of my data:

[image]

What I want to do is have three cells each with a data validation drop down list. If you select AA in the first one, the second drop down list would only show col2.1, col2.2, and col2.3 as options. If you then selected col2.1 from that list (while leaving AA selected), the third list would only show apple and grape.

Ideally, this dependence wouldn't be one directional, so if I selected orange in the third dropdown list, AA and BB would be options in the first dropdown list, and col2.2 and col2.c in the second dropdown list.

***Important***
I am working with large amounts of dynamic data, so a solution that requires naming ranges manually will not work.

Comment: What have you done so far? Where is your problem?

Comment: So, name the ranges dynamically. That's why the "Refers to" box takes formulas.